# GhostScript issue with extracting text, and -dProvideUnicode usage

Tags: ghostscript

I use GS with DjVu driver, as in this example:

`gs %gs_args% -dProvideUnicode -dExtractText -sDEVICE=djvusep -o out.sep in.ps`

and noticed issue, that with some files text is not correctly extracted (I get question marks in clipboard on copying text from generated file).

I thought it's some issue with encoding, and removed `-dProvideUnicode` switch, but then text is not extracted at all, and I assume that `-dExtractText` flag, specific only to this driver, needs it to function properly.

Trying to run single page PDF file (that generated `in.ps` through `ps2write` device), with `ps2ascii` gives also no text. But other tools like pdfminer, xpdf, extract correct text. Also PDF viewers like SumatraPDF that uses `mupdf`, or Acrobat, extract the text as expected.

Does anyone maybe knows something about these undocumented switches, and what could be the problem here?

**Update**: This only happens if I go through `ps2write` route. If instead I use PDF directly there is no issue.

Here is encoding info from the PDF file:

```
c:\temp>pdf-parser -s encoding sample.pdf
obj 11 0
 Type: /Font
 Referencing: 12 0 R, 20 0 R

  <<
    /BaseFont /XQKNMY+TT14112O00
    /FontDescriptor 12 0 R
    /Type /Font
    /FirstChar 32
    /LastChar 144
    /Widths [
253 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 293 293 0 0 220 313 220 0
0 467 467 0 0 0 467 0 467 467 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 680 0 0 0 653 0 773 760 0 0 740 0 833 0 0
0 0 0 480 613 0 680 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 407 513 414 500 414 320 447 513 227 0 467 227 773 513 513
513 0 333 367 293 487 467 667 460 414 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
220]
    /Encoding 20 0 R
    /Subtype /Type1
  >>

obj 20 0
 Type: /Encoding
 Referencing:

  <<
    /Type /Encoding
    /BaseEncoding /WinAnsiEncoding
    /Differences [
144/quoteright]
  >>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a Ghostscript question. The djvu device is decidedly non-standard in a Ghostscript build. I can't tell you anything about the switches, because they are specific to the DejaVu device.

If all you want to do is extract the text from a file you could use the txtwrite device (with recent versions of Ghostscript).

If you use a PDF file then a ToUnicode CMap may be present in the file and can be used to get Unicode information about the text. PostScript does not contain ToUnicode CMaps and so the Unicode information is *NOT* available from the PostScript file. I would imagine this is why the ps2write output can't have text extracted from it by the device.

Comment: `-dProvideUnicode` is GS switch AFAIK. Most PS files does correctly send text contents to djvu device, but some not - and I wonder why? As I updated my question, if I use PDF directly then text context is correctly passed, but if I use PS from same PDF file generated by `ps2write` device, then correct text content depends on something and it's not clear to me what. I understand however that this is very narrow question, but `-dProvideUnicode` is really not documented anywhere. BTW I managed to build GS and DjVu device with MSVC, and everything works cleanly, and with PDF input support

Comment: -dProviceUnicode is, basically, not used. Its intended to force the PDF interpreter to parse ToUnicode CMaps, and TrueType fonts loaded as CIDFont replacements to acquire a GlyphNames2Unicode CMap. Its usage depends on a device which is able to handle these. No standard Ghostscript device uses -dProvideUnicode, the pdfwrite device (which can handle ToUnicode CMaps) has a different method to force parsing of ToUnicde CMaps. This switch is essentially obselete

Comment: As I said earlier, you can't put ToUnicode information into a PostScript file, so the output of ps2write doesn't have it, and therefore it can't be used. There are other ways to try and get 'meaningful' text from PostScript files, none of them are reliable. Clearly the font isn't assembled in a way which the device can extract this information. Not too surprising, every time you do a transformation you lose information, limit the transformations to the absolutely essential ones.

Comment: Looking in gsdjvu source, there is function for `-dExtractText` switch, which apparently replaced previously used [ps2utf8.ps](http://sourceforge.net/p/djvu/gsdjvu-git/ci/58aa9f2a079eb7051c94afea14c7b46dbac110b3/tree/ps2utf8.ps) script through `-dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT` switches to new possibility `-dProvideUnicode -dExtractText`

Comment: gsdjvu is not part of the standard Ghostscript release, so I can't comment on it. There is a Ghostscript standard device (txtwrite) which can extract text.